# no resource id found for app:layout_scrollflags from CollapsingToolbarLayout

Tags: android, androiddesignsupport, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

The title of this question basically says it all. I get the error:
no resource identifier found for app:layout_scrollflags from CollapsingToolbarLayout. I use eclipse and imported the design library jar file. I'm able to use the design support layouts in my classes so that's correct

this is a piece of the code i use:

```
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@color/activityBg"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
>

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <include
            layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

examples: http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html

Comment: BTW this need to be in an `AppBarLayout` inside a `CoordinatorLayout`.

Comment: still not working after putting it in a appbarlayout

Answer (score 29, accepted):

only importing the design library jar file is not enough. You need to import resource of **android-design-library** project while the jar file only contains class files.

Do as I say:

1. import **android-design-library** project. The project is at
   "**sdk/extras/android/support/design/**". And set it as a library
   project if it is not.
2. import the above project into your main project as a library.

You have to do this, because `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` means your need local resources from your library project or the current project, in this case, it means you need resources from  the library project of **android-design-library**.

Comment: i got errors in design library after importing at style.xml file

Comment: Can you provide more details?

Answer (score 28):

try this

add app level **build.gradle**

```
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
```

then **Build** -> **Rebuild Project**

Comment: Will sdk level 23 work instead of 24 in this condition?

Comment: yes, you should change

from 
compile 'com.android.support:design:23._._'

to
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'

you need not use 24.2.1..
you can replace new version

Comment: 'compile' is deprecated and must use 'api' (precompiled library).  The version has to match your compiler.  The IDE sync will provide the proper aids.

Answer (score 6):

As others have stated you definitely need to add [Design Support Library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages.html#design) dependency to your android app. Simplest way is to add following to app level gradle file -

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
```

However couple of points to note-

1. This support library should not use a different version than the compileSdkVersion. Since I was using `compileSdkVersion 25` I had to use `compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'` and not `compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'`
2. Using the design library requires using theme.appcompat or a descendant. If you want add actionbar to your activity then your theme should be AppCompat. In my case I was using `android:Theme.Material` due to which it was failing. Changing it to `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

### Androidx soution:

If you are using [AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx) the above solutions **won't work**.

You will need to implement this:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha06'
```

Notice that Maybe you will need to `Invalidate Caches/Restart` for this to work for you:

> File > Invalidate Caches/Restart

For more info check the [Migrating to AndroidX page](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate).

Answer (score 2):

Try add this code to the xml file:

```
app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior"
```

Answer (score 1):

For this you should use this type of hierarchy of layouts.
Make sure the design support library is included as a reference project in the case of eclipse

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbarlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivProfileImage"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:contentDescription="@null"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:minHeight="100dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="top|start"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" >
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: still doesn't work after i put the whole thing in a appbarlayout

Comment: try to remove linear layout and put it in a cordinator layout and the other content in nested scroll view. I recently implemented it and it is working fine

Comment: did u use eclipse or android studio?

Comment: did you add any jars to get the design support library to work other then appcompat v4/v7

Comment: No just used the project design `(design support library)` from sdk as a reference project.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82179/discussion-between-gopal-singh-sirvi-and-user2395334).

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I did

1. Import **AppCompat V7** from  *

> C:\Productivity\android-sdks\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat

and **Check copy into workspace** in import project dialog box.

2. Target Android Build version of apcompat to Android 6.0 from

> Project->Properties->Android

it should remove  all compilation error.

3. Import **Design Lib** from

> C:\Productivity\android-sdks\extras\android\support\design

follow same steps to import project mentioned in 1 & 2.

4. Mark imported design lib as Android lib and if it show error Add AppCompat V7 lib into Build path of your design lib from

> Project->Properties->Android.

5. Finally add design and appcompat to build path of Your Android project

   Project->Properties->Android

clean and build your project with Android 6.0 all compilation errors must be gone by now.

**Congrats now you can use material design in Eclipse.Hope it will help somebody**

Answer (score 0):

Add an app level build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

the version should match to your compileSdkVersion. I used version 28.